# CSS Grid Center (Justify) Item Based on Row Width Instead of Item Width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am wondering how I can justify an item using CSS Grid to the center of the row instead of just the specific item. In the snippet below, you can see how `child2` (the red one) is centered only within that item, not the center of the entire row - it is a little too far to the right.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Here is a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/6ytqk7rL/

```css
#parent {
  display:inline-grid;
  width:100%;
  grid-template-columns: [logo] 50px [title] auto;
  justify-items: center;
}
.child {
 background: blue;
 height:30px;
 width:30px;
}
#child2 {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="child1" class="child">

</div>
<div id="child2" class="child">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add empty 50px at the right `grid-template-columns: [logo] 50px [title] auto 50px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the red square to be central to the whole row, you'll need to offset it by the width of the first `<div>`that is to its left.

As elements, it current appears as follows:

[image]

So the red square is centrally aligned within its container.  It can't automatically judge its position based on a parent - as a result, if you add a `margin-left: -50px` this compensates for the `#child1` width you've defined in `grid-templates-columns`.

[image]